# query Marionette.js collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I would like to perform fairly complex filtering on Marionette Collections.
Is there way to search for models with a DB like querys like the MongoDB API?

Example:

```
MarionetteCollection.find( 
{
 type: 'product',
 $or: [ { qty: { $gt: 100 } }, { price: { $lt: 9.95 } } ],
 $and [ { active: true} ],
 $sortby{'name'},
 $order {'asc'}
});
```

Maybe an extension to Marionette.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in `Marionette` to help you here and `Marionette` doesn't make any changes/additions to the regular `Backbone.Collection`.

You could take a look at [`backbone-query`](https://github.com/davidgtonge/backbone_query). It appears to do what you are wanting.

Comment: Will try that. If it works with Marionette, its the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has a simple implementation of what you are asking. Collection.where() && Collection.findWhere() can take an object and will find the model based on your object. But it doesn't more complex matchings like, greater than, less than, etc.

```
MarionetteCollection.find( 
{
 type: 'product',
 qty: 55,
 active: true
});
```